# Is it possible to realease a full set of potentially dependant artifacts (microservices) at once?

Tags: azure-devops

Traditionally we have to deliver our applications on the test and pre-production platforms one by one (usually by hand using setups). Applications like the front end javascript SPA UI are linked to backend services and their delivery sometimes goes together.
 Each service and each application has its own git repository. (we are using on premise TFS 2018 for now )
 Then when it is necessary to go into production, we deliver all of the front end services and applications at once that have been validated at once.

We would like to automate our process but we don't know if Azure Devops is suitable.
  From what I understand with Azure Devops, we can make an independent artifact for each microservice and each front end application. We can also deliver them independently.

It seems to me that Azure Devops by default allows you to manage the delivery cycle for a particular microservice but not for an assembly making up a complete system, right?

But is it possible to deliver a set of projects each with a particular version? For that, must all of our projects be in the same solution or the same git repository?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use multiple artifacts from different sources (build artifacts, repositories, package feeds, github, docker hub, Azure Container Registry, ++) within a single pipeline or release definition. That's true for both the classic release definitions and the modern multi-stage pipeline implementation.

For example you can define a pipeline or release definition that consumes a front-end web app from a build artifact sourced from RepoA, a back-end service artifact consumed from a container registry originally from RepoB, and say a script library in the form of a Git artifact from RepoC. From there you could deploy each of those artifacts together, or in parallel stages, in sequence, partially, with approvals, conditionally, etc, all from the same pipeline.

The full configuration as code YAML [multi-stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/multi-stage-pipelines-experience?view=azure-devops) pipelines are still in preview, so there are some workflow orchestrations that are a little tougher to implement. But there is enough [feature parity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-get-started?view=azure-devops#feature-availability) with the classic release definitions that I would default to using multi-stage for any net new needs.

Comment: Yes indeed I have seen after asking my question that we could have multiple artifacts as input of the release pipeline. But what I do not know : is for example we validate a version of the global system on PreProd environnment with lets say 2 microservices : Service.AUTH.Api version 1.02.03 and service.Product.API 1.01.01 is we could push the two exact same validated version on production in on release pipeline or does we one have to specify the same version to deliver for each deliver for the production environnment.